# F#: is no-op printf possible?

Tags: f#

I have a couple of wrappers of `Printf`-family API (e.g. for logging)

```
  type Logger(writer: TextWriter) =
    ...
    member x.Log (fmt: PrintfFormat<'Printer, _, _, _>): 'Printer =
      Printf.fprintfn writer fmt
```

Let's say I want to introduce the notion of "log level" to it, add `Logger.Info()`, `Debug()`, `Trace()` *etc.* which are basically another layer on top of `Logger.Log()`, and if `logger.Level <- LogLevel.Info` then `Debug()` and `Trace()` should turn into no-ops. Pretty common requirement, I'd say.

But I can't seem to return a `'Printer`-typed value without actually calling any of `Printf`-family API.

```
type LogLevel = TRACE | DEBUG | INFO

type LevelLogger(writer: TextWriter, level: LogLevel) =
  inherit Logger(writer)
  member x.Info (fmt: PrintfFormat<'Printer, _, _, _>): 'Printer =
    if level <= LogLevel.INFO then
      x.Log fmt
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
```

> warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'Printer has been constrained to be type 'unit'.

```
let l0 = Logger(Console.Error)
l0.Log "foo %d %s %f" 1 "foo" 1.23

let l1 = LevelLogger(Console.Error, LogLevel.INFO)
l1.Info "foo %d %s %f" 1 "foo" 1.23
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
> 'unit'
> but here has type
> ''a -> string -> 'b -> unit'
> error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied.

It would be ideal if I could write

```
  member x.Info (fmt: PrintfFormat<'Printer, _, _, _>): 'Printer =
    if level <= LogLevel.INFO then x.Log fmt
                              else Printf.noop fmt
```

But does there exist such a utility API? Or can we write one?

Workarounds just for "getting things done" that I'm aware of:

1. `fprintfn TextWriter.Null`, I believe, still formats all args and can be unnecessarily expensive
2. `kbprintfn` with a continuation that conditionally calls `writer.WriteLine(sb)` has the same issue
3. In C++ codebase, this kind of dynamic config is often complemented with [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-directives) (`#if` ...), like, enabling `TRACE` level only under `-DDEBUG`; but I don't know if we can write an ergonomic API with them in F#.

Also, `PrintfFormat` is always allocated out of a format string anyways, then the "no-op" API can never be a real no-op? But I'm hoping it might still be much light-weight than `TextWriter.Null`, if that's ever possible.

Ahhh why is `PrintfImpl` `internal`??

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs

## Update: My attempts so far

https://sharplab.io/#gist:70dd6f915ba14f36c122f601732af1c1

`LevelLogger0` doesn't type check, and my understanding is that both `LevelLogger1` and `2` would waste CPU & RAM in `logger.Trace "%A" (Array.zeroCreate<double> 1_000_000_000)` even when the current threshold is `INFO`.

Comment: `kprintf` should work just fine. Can you show your attempt with it?

Comment: 3rd workaround can be implemented with  [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I added a sharplab link

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same a time ago and did not find a solution.

Meanwhile string interpolation was added and I find it better at all ends over F#s safe but (as we see here a bit tricky) printf. String interpolation is type safe, improves readability and leads to less brackets. Another disadvantage of printf is its behavior during debugging.

I do logging with an extension method that has the Conditional attribute

type ILogger with // this is Serilog.ILogger which I use

```
[<Conditional("LOG")>]
member o.InformationConditional(s: string) =
    o.Information(s)
```

to be used like

```
let a = 72
let b = "hello"
logger.InformationConditional($"foo {a} bar {b}")
```

Keeping with printf you can create the string with sprintf.

Comment: Thanks for the info. From what I read about it, it's a nicely wrapped version of #ifdef DEBUG

Comment: what do you mean, the ConditionalAttribute?

Comment: Yup,`[<Conditional("LOG")>]` conceptually have `logger.InformationConditional($"foo {a} bar {b}")` surrounded by `#ifdef LOG ... #endif`, right? That's how I understood the way it works

Comment: Yepp, that is valid. The big deal is that the arguments passed to the conditional operation are never evaluated, so the string interpolation, which might hold more or less expensive arguments is never evaluated.

Comment: Skipping evaluation of expensive arguments is great, but the major limitation of this approach is it's a compile-time flag, can't be used for something like live config reload

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get something like your `Printf.noop` is to use `Printf.kprintf`, which takes a continuation that is called with the composed string. If you pass `ignore` as the continuation, this does nothing. However, this unfortunately does not quite work:

```
  member x.Info (fmt: PrintfFormat<'Printer, _, _, _>): 'Printer =
    if level <= LogLevel.INFO then x.Log fmt
    else Printf.kprintf ignore fmt
```

This would logically do the trick, but the issue is that the type of `fmt` expected by `kprintf` and `fprintf` differs (in that they have a different state). So, if you want to do this, you will always need to use `kprintf` and then decide what to do based on the log level inside the continuation:

```
  member x.Info (fmt: PrintfFormat<'Printer, _, _, _>): 'Printer =
    fmt |> Printf.kprintf (fun s ->
      if level <= LogLevel.INFO then x.Log "%s" s)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's basically my workaround 2 "`kbprintf` with a continuation that conditionally calls `writer.WriteLine(sb)`" if I'm not mistaken